# Картинка с ссылкой размножилась (HTML + CSS)

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Я пишу для себя мини магазин, так вот когда нажимаешь на Detail тебя должно перевести на страницу где описание кроссовок. Но у меня что то пошло не так, картинка Detail (ее стало слишком много)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там по сути должна быть одна картинка "Detail" чтобы нажав на нее тебя перекидывало на другую страницу, странно что перекидывает но картинки Детойл слишком много, как можно сделать так чтобы для каждого товара она была одна.

Вот мой HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Shoes Store from templatemo</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ddsmoothmenu.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ddsmoothmenu.js">

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        ddsmoothmenu.init({
            mainmenuid: "top_nav", //menu DIV id
            orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
            classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
            //customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
            contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
        })

    </script>

</head>

<body>
<h1 align="center">Mini Shop on Spring Framework by Adil</h1>
<div data-th-each="product : ${products}" class="product product_box">
    <h3 data-th-text="${product.title}"></h3>
    <a data-th-href="@{/catalog/products/{productId}(productId=${product.id})}" class="detail"><img src="/images/product/01.jpg" alt="Shoes 1"  /></a>
    <p data-th-text="${product.description}"></p>
    <p class="product_price">34000 Тенге</p>
    <a data-th-href="@{/catalog/products/{productId}(productId=${product.id})}" class="detail"></a>
</div>

<div class="cleaner"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Вот мой CSS там пару раз используется класс Detail скорее всего там совершил ошибку

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #999;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    background-color: #665f5f;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-image: url(images/fon.png)
}

a, a:link, a:visited { color: #0299aa; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

a.addtocart{ display: inline-block; width: 80px; height: 21px; line-height: 21px; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #333; background: url(images/templatemo_addtocart.png) }
```

////// ВОТ

```
a.detail{


    text-align: center;


    padding-bottom: 30px;

    background: url(images/templatemo_detail.png) }






h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { color: #333; font-weight: normal; }
h1
{   font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5px 0

}
h2 { font-size: 26px; margin: 0 0 25px; padding: 5px 0 }
h3 { font-size: 20px; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 0; }
h4 { font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0; }
h5 { font-size: 14px; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;  }
h6 { font-size: 12px; margin: 0 0 5px; padding: 0; }

.cleaner { clear: both }
.h10 { height: 10px }
.h20 { height: 20px }
.h30 { height: 30px }
.h40 { height: 40px }
.h50 { height: 50px }


.float_r {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40em;

}





.bs_box { clear: both; margin-bottom: 20px }
.bs_box img { float: left; margin-right: 10px; border: 4px solid #fff }
.bs_box h4 { margin-bottom: 0 }
.bs_box h4 a { font-size: 11px; color: #000; font-weight: 700}
.bs_box .price { font-size: 12px; font-weight: 700; color: #11bdd1}

.product_box {

    width: 30em;

    text-align: center;

    display:inline-block;

    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc
}

.product_box img {
    margin-bottom: 5px;

}
.product_box h3 {
    font-size: 11px;

    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.product_box .product_price {
    color: #11bdd1;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.product_box .addtocart {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

/////ВОТ

```
.product_box .detail {
    float: right;
    display: block;

}
```

Comment: сделайте эту кнопку не картинкой а блоком или button

Answer (score 0):

проблема с background. Это скомбинированное свойство и ты прописал тольно путь, в ней же есть функция background-repeat, по умолчанию она копирует кртинку на всё пространство, нужно задать ей no-repeat, почтитай документацию про background.

Answer (score 0):

Замените эти свойства:

```
background-color: #665f5f;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-image: url(images/fon.png);
```

На:

```
background: #665f5f url(images/fon.png) no-repeat;
```

Тогда изображение не будет повторяться.